# Moving Method causes blackout logic to not work in Unity VR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, virtual-reality

I have a method called alternateCoverTest which compares values of eye positions in VR and changes the position of a target based on prism values.

I want this method to only be called when the left eye is covered, and I am using a loop in the update method to do so such that even values of my loopCounter cover the right eye, and odd values cover the right eye.

If the method is outside either even/odd loop conditions, the logic works perfectly. But moving the method inside just the odd loopCounters causes the right eye to only be covered for a single frame. Not for the entire duration of the loop, when the method is outside the even/odd if statements.

I dont know where/why the logical error is occurring.

This is in the update method

```
if (DistantTestActive == true)
        {
            DistantHeterophoriaTest();
            updateBlackoutPosition();

            if (HeterophoriaTestTimer >= HeterophoriaTestInterval)
            {
                if (loopCounter >= 3)
                {
                    updateTargetPosition(new Vector3(0, 2, 6), new Vector3(.10f, .10f, .10f));

                    if (loopCounter % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        leftEyeIsCovered = true; rightEyeIsCovered = false;
                        calculateRightEyePosition();
                        alternateCoverTest();
                    }

                    if (loopCounter % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        leftEyeIsCovered = false; rightEyeIsCovered = true;
                    }
                }

                loopCounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                HeterophoriaTestTimer = HeterophoriaTestTimer + Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
```

Here is the method I want to move.

```
   private void alternateCoverTest()
    {
        if (firstCheck == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Initial run without prism. " + prism + " diopters of prism." + " Current DeltaX: " + currentEyePosition.x +
                " Current DeltaY: " + currentEyePosition.y + " Current DeltaZ: " + currentEyePosition.z);
            HeterophoriaTestTimer = 0f;
            prism = 2f;
            firstCheck = false;
            Debug.Log("Error is in first Check");
        }

        else if (secondCheck == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Second run with 2 units of prism: " + prism + " diopters of prism " + " Current DeltaX: " + currentEyePosition.x +
                      " Current DeltaY: " + currentEyePosition.y + " Current DeltaZ: " + currentEyePosition.z);
            HeterophoriaTestTimer = 0f;
            secondCheck = false;
            Debug.Log("Error is in second Check");
        }

        else if (Mathf.Abs(currentEyePosition.x) <= Mathf.Abs(previousEyePosition.x))
        {
            Debug.Log("Adding positive horizontal prism: " + prism + " diopters of prism " + " Current DeltaX: " + currentEyePosition.x +
                      " Current DeltaY: " + currentEyePosition.y + " Current DeltaZ: " + currentEyePosition.z);
            HeterophoriaTestTimer = 0f;
            prism = prism + 2;
            directionX = "XP";
            Debug.Log("Error is in + Check");
        }

        else if (Mathf.Abs(currentEyePosition.x) >= Mathf.Abs(previousEyePosition.x))
        {
            Debug.Log("Adding negative horizontal prism: " + prism + " diopters of prism " + " Current DeltaX: " + currentEyePosition.x +
                      " Current DeltaY: " + currentEyePosition.y + " Current DeltaZ: " + currentEyePosition.z);
            HeterophoriaTestTimer = 0f;
            prism = prism - 2;
            directionX = "EP";
            Debug.Log("Error is in - Check");
        }

        else { Debug.Log("Error in unilateralCoverTestLogic"); }

        previousEyePosition = currentEyePosition;

        prismChange(prism);

        if (Mathf.Abs(currentEyePosition.x) <= Threshold.x)
        {
            distantPrism = prism; prism = 0f;
            Debug.Log("Final prism value of : " + directionX + distantPrism + " diopters of prism " + " Current DeltaX: " + currentEyePosition.x +
                      " Current DeltaY: " + currentEyePosition.y + " Current DeltaZ: " + currentEyePosition.z);
            DistantTestActive = false;
            updateTargetPosition(new Vector3(0, 2, 29), new Vector3(.1f, .1f, .1f));
            HeterophoriaTestTimer = 0f;
            rightEyeIsCovered = false; leftEyeIsCovered = false; updateBlackoutPosition();
            firstCheck = true; secondCheck = true;
            Debug.Log("Error is in comparison Check");
        }
    }
```

Here is the updateBlackoutPosition method if its helpful.

````
private void updateBlackoutPosition()
{
    REyeAnchorPosition = REyeInteractor.transform;
    LEyeAnchorPosition = LEyeInteractor.transform;
    if (leftEyeIsCovered == true && rightEyeIsCovered == false)
    {
        Blackout.layer = 12;
        blackoutTransform = LEyeInteractor.transform;
        blackoutTransform.rotation = LEyeInteractor.transform.rotation;
        Blackout.transform.position = blackoutTransform.position + blackoutOffset;
        Blackout.transform.rotation = blackoutTransform.rotation;
        Blackout.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.6f, .6f, .0001f);
        Debug.Log("Issue is 1 check");
    }

    else if (leftEyeIsCovered == false && rightEyeIsCovered == true)
    {
        Blackout.layer = 13;
        blackoutTransform = REyeInteractor.transform;
        blackoutTransform.rotation = REyeInteractor.transform.rotation;
        Blackout.transform.position = blackoutTransform.position + blackoutOffset;
        Blackout.transform.rotation = blackoutTransform.rotation;
        Blackout.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.6f, .6f, .0001f);
        Debug.Log("Issue is 2 check");
    }

    else if (leftEyeIsCovered == false && rightEyeIsCovered == false && (DistantTestActive == true || NearTestActive == true || calibrateEyes == true))
    {
        Blackout.layer = 0;
        blackoutTransform = centerEyeAnchorTransform;
        Blackout.transform.position = blackoutTransform.position + new Vector3 (0,-.1f,.1f);
        Blackout.transform.rotation = blackoutTransform.rotation;
        Blackout.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.005f, .005f, .005f);
        Debug.Log("Issue is 3rd check");
    }

    else if (leftEyeIsCovered == false && rightEyeIsCovered == false && (DistantTestActive == false && NearTestActive == false && calibrateEyes == false))
    {
        Blackout.layer = 0;
        blackoutTransform.position = new Vector3(5, 20, 5);
        Blackout.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.6f, .6f, .0001f);
        Debug.Log("Issue is 4 check");
    }

    else { Debug.Log("Error in updateBlackOutPosition Method Logic."); }

}```
````